# Save the values in a userform in vba so they show up on userform after a user saves, exits, and reopen's the doc?

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have multiple userform pages connected to a word document that a user can simply fill out in a form like fashion to populate/generate a document, however I'm having an issue if for instance on userform page 1 a user completes it and clicks the "save/next page" command button and then on the next page they decide to exit out the form and complete the remaining portion at another time since the document is saved and the questions on page 1 have been fully answered and populated in the word doc.

The issue is when the user re-open's the document they are often confused about why the answers they filled out previously aren't still inputted into the userform (They are in the word document still), but it doesn't show the users answers in the text/combo boxes on the userform. Anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: You would need to save/load the values from an INI file or similar file.

Comment: Here is Microsoft's article with 5 methods to store data between macro sessions: Document Variables, Document Properties, AutoText, Settings (INI) files and using the Registry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends

Comment: Save the values as document variables and pull them back in the initialize procedure.

Comment: How do you place the answers in the word doc? Via fields, bookmarks, content controls? Using content controls, you could use content control tags that are equal to the names of the text boxes in your user form. By this mapping you can write the values from the user form to the content controls or - vice versa - write them from the content controls to the text boxes when opening the form ... all done via two generic routines.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I have them saved as document variables/bookmarks, is there a way to pull in both during the initialize procedure and what would that look like? My idea was the code below in the initialize: 
Load userform1 
With ActiveDocument
    .Fields.Update
End With
However this didn't get the job done

Comment: Sorry, I do a couple of UserForms a year and have to check my resources. Here are my starting places: http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userForm.html http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm (see taking it a step further) https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/interactive_userforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the [code Word MVP Graham Mayor uses](http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm) to take data already in document variables to reinitialize a form:

> ```
> Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
> Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
> Caption = "My Example Form"
> Label1.Caption = "Forename"
> Label2.Caption = "Surname"
> Label3.Caption = "Phone Number"
> CommandButton1.Caption = "OK"
> CommandButton2.Caption = "Cancel"
> On Error Resume Next
> 'Read the values from the document variables if they exist
> TextBox1.value = oVars("var1").value
> TextBox2.value = oVars("var2").value
> TextBox3.value = oVars("var3").value
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: How do I do this for comboboxes if I just want the selected item to appear? @CharlesKenyon